# Ruby on Rails as an appliance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to package my rails application as an appliance on a virtual machine that has a database already setup in postgres? When such appliance is run, it should simply run the rails application and be ready for use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any obstacles for that, you just have to [configure database connection URL](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#connection-preference) to Postgres upfront through env var at VM, so Rails (ActiveRecord) will pick up it during launch.

But if you require packing consider to look at containers, particularly [Docker](https://www.docker.com).